# CSS3 3D Transitions flickering in firefox when also using box-shadow

Tags: html, firefox, css, css-transitions

I have an apple like coverflow element built using CSS3 transition and 3D transforms.

http://jsfiddle.net/7eDkb/1/ (Transition with box-shadow)

Works smooth on chrome, but on firefox, the covers are flickering between being visible and invisible when they are being animated.

After an elimination process, i have found that removing the "box-shadow" css property from the items results in smooth transitions in firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/7eDkb/2/ (Transition without box-shadow)

I have tested this in firefox v15 and chrome v21.

Is there a solution to having both 3d transitions and box-shadow on an element without it flickering on firefox?

**EDIT:** in the fiddles, click gray images to see flickering

Comment: You could replace the shadow with an image for Firefox only. This would require some javascript, so it might now be the best solution. I think that Firefox's rendering engine isn't really there yet. Props to Chrome :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good reason no one answered this question yet, It's a firefox bug.

I've submitted this to bugzilla, and it was confirmed as a bug.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=790239

As @Kyle stated in his comment, the current best solution is to use a non-elegant alternative to box-shadow in the case of firefox.